# Facepile with graph api

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

I want to display the list of the user's friends who made an Open Graph action, like cooking. I can do this with Facepile, but how can I do this with the Graph API in order to control how it's displayed?

I can't find the corresponding Graph API call. Is there a simple way in order to avoid multiple Graph API calls?

Comment: I modify the question.


I can't find the corresponding graph api call. Is there a simple way in order to avoid multiple graph api call?

Comment: You want to find out if a user's friend has published an OpenGraph action similar to those in your app?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook should make api for that, but there is not way currently. I asked the technical support in facebook.com for that. They have a plan to implemente in FQL, but not yet.
So, facepile is only way until now. Check http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/ and check other type of codes like javascript SDK or iframe.